# By Excel VBA, adding 'NONE' option in a multi-select dropdown list created with data validation

Tags: excel, vba, validation, if-statement, dropdownlistfor

By the kind help of Dear @Taller, below code adds checkmarks to debut of each option in a multi-select dropdown list created with data validation. However, I got a feedback/criticize from my manager regarding the situation that a 'NONE' option should have been added in the list. When 'NONE' is selected the remaining options cannot be and when the other options are selected the 'NONE' cannot be selected at the same time. Is it possible to solve this problem by VBA coding? Thank you very much in advance.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Oldvalue As String
    Dim Newvalue As String

    Application.EnableEvents = True

    On Error GoTo Exitsub

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F4:F29")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
            GoTo Exitsub
        Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
            Application.EnableEvents = False

            Newvalue = Target.Value
            Application.Undo
            Oldvalue = Target.Value

            If Oldvalue = "" Then
                Target.Value = Newvalue
            Else
                If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
                    If AscW(Left(Oldvalue, 1)) <> &H2713 Then
                        Oldvalue = ChrW(&H2713) & Space(1) & Oldvalue
                    End If

                    Target.Value = Oldvalue & vbNewLine & ChrW(&H2713) & Space(1) & Newvalue
                Else:
                    Target.Value = Oldvalue
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

Exitsub:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: showing your attempts along with its results would help you getting help

Comment: Please, **better explain the meaning** of "When 'NONE' is selected the remaining options cannot be and when the other options are selected the 'NONE' cannot be selected at the same time"... If I understood that 1: 'NONE' can be selected only if no other selection exists and after it nothing can be selected, or 2: 'NONE' cannot be selected anymore if at least one previous selection has been done, would it be correct? Please, think about it and clarify the issue. We don't care to much about your boss will. YOU must explain what you need, from the point of view put in discussion...

Comment: Sorry, i wasn't at the computer. What you said is exactly right. If 'NONE' is selected, other options should not be accepted into the cell. Likewise, if an option other than 'NONE' was previously selected, 'NONE' should not be accepted into the cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not so clear in terms of what is to be done when 'NONE' is selected. I asked a clarification question but you did not answer it. The next code clears the validation list if you select 'NONE' in **an empty such list validated cell** and **keeps only the previous selected items in the validation list when you select 'NONE'**:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Oldvalue As String, Newvalue As String

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    On Error GoTo Exitsub

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F4:F29")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
            GoTo Exitsub
        Else: If Target.value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
            Application.EnableEvents = False

            Newvalue = Target.value
            Application.Undo
            Oldvalue = Target.value

            If Oldvalue = "" Then
                Target.value = Newvalue
                If Newvalue = "NONE" Then
                    Target.Validation.Delete 'delete the cell validation if nothing existed in cell
                End If
            Else
                If Newvalue = "NONE" Then
                    'extract the existing validating list:
                    Dim exList: exList = Split(Target.value, vbNewLine)
                    With Target.Validation
                        .Delete
                        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                                                  Formula1:=Join(exList, ",") 'keep only existing Target values
                    End With
                Else
                    If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
                        If AscW(left(Oldvalue, 1)) <> &H2713 Then
                            Oldvalue = ChrW(&H2713) & space(1) & Oldvalue
                        End If
    
                        Target.value = Oldvalue & vbNewLine & ChrW(&H2713) & space(1) & Newvalue
                    Else:
                        Target.value = Oldvalue
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If

Exitsub:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

The above code treats the validation list obtained by inputting a comma separated string in `Source`...

If you validate in a different way, it is time to explain how you do it.

**Edited**:

Please, use the next version. It should do what (I understood) you need:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Oldvalue As String, Newvalue As String

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    On Error GoTo Exitsub

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F4:F29")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
            GoTo Exitsub
        Else: If Target.value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
            Application.EnableEvents = False

            Newvalue = Target.value
            Application.Undo
            Oldvalue = Target.value

            If Oldvalue = "" Then
                Target.value = Newvalue
            ElseIf Oldvalue = "NONE" Then
                'DO NOTHING...
            Else
                If Newvalue = "NONE" Then GoTo Exitsub
                If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
                    If AscW(left(Oldvalue, 1)) <> &H2713 Then
                        Oldvalue = ChrW(&H2713) & space(1) & Oldvalue
                    End If

                    Target.value = Oldvalue & vbNewLine & ChrW(&H2713) & space(1) & Newvalue
                Else:
                    Target.value = Oldvalue
                End If
            End If
         End If
    End If

Exitsub:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: The code you wrote partially did what I wanted. I would like to ask that is there a way for reaching goal without deleting data validation.

Comment: @PYC If you define **the goal** it certainly should be a way... So **what do you want happening after 'None' pressing, if nothing exists in the respective cell**? To write 'NONE', but from that moment nothing to be accepted, even if the list validation exists? Then, the second part, the one related with 'NONE' choice **after some previous options existence**, is what you need, or after solving the first part you will come back with this one?

Comment: Actually, yes, as you said, when 'NONE' is selected, other options appear in the list, but they cannot be selected in the cell. On the other hand, in the presence of options other than 'NONE' in the cell, only the 'NONE' option is not accepted into the cell but appears in the list. When clearing the cell content, the list returns to its original form again.

Comment: @PYC I cannot get you. Somehow clearer the issue of 'NONE' selected when nothing was previously selected. With other clearer words. Nothing is changed in the list, but **if 'NONE' is selected, NOTHING will be done if the user tries selecting an item**. I do not understand what to be done when already are selections and choose 'NONE'.  Do you mean to not interfere in the validation list, but **if somebody choose 'NONE', nothing to be happening**? Working without clarifying of what you want is waste of time. So, please do what I initially required...

Comment: @PYC Please, test the version I posted after **Edited** and send some feedback.

Comment: It works flawlessly, thank you for your effort and time. i am really grateful to you. Thank you soooooo much.

Comment: @PYC Glad I could help! But you must learn that we cannot help you if we cannot clearly understand what you need... If difficult to be explained in words, pictures showing the initial case and the desired output for both cases could help.